# Image from web for UITableViewCell: fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

I've got a problem with my images. The following code works in a tableViewController but doesn't work in my CollectionView.

this works...

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = listOfVideos[indexPath.row]?.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = listOfVideos[indexPath.row]?.duration

    let imgUrl = listOfVideos[indexPath.row]?.videoImgUrl
    do {
        let bindData = try Data(contentsOf: imgUrl!)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: bindData)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return cell
}
```

this doesn't work

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    let imgUrl = listOfImages[indexPath.row]?.imagePreviewUrl

    do {
        let bindData = try Data(contentsOf: imgUrl!)
        cell.img.image = UIImage(data: bindData)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return cell
}
```

The url is valid and the image exists. The error "fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" occurred when UIImage(data: bindData) is called.

Thanks Tom

Comment: is your cell.img a valid imageView ? Have you tried to print your bindData ?

Comment: I think so. The content of data:
`Printing description of bindData:
▿ 56894 bytes
  - count : 56894
  ▿ pointer : 0x00007ffed599b810
    - pointerValue : 140732482041872
`
The imageView comes from an UIImageViewCell wich is registered by `self.collectionView!.register(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`

Comment: To help you out, try moving UIImage(data: bindData) one line above like: let img = UIImage(data: bindData) next line cell.img.image = img, then you can see where it is stopping. It will not solve your problem but at least will help you isolating the problem.

Comment: sometimes it's hard to find when the error occurs. But I tried your way, now it's a little clearer. It stopped at the last line. cell.img... and in Preview I can see the image. But when I let print the Data it says:
`Printing description of img:
expression produced error: error: /var/folders/t1/9c481wfn4xd6v89j37n6gzjr0000gn/T/./lldb/19631/expr1.swift:1:80: error: use of undeclared type 'UIKit'
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.Optional<UIKit.UIImage>>(bitPattern: 0x11d302710)!.pointee)`

Comment: It seems to be the cell. If I add an ImageView outside the cell. It works. So, now I don't know to hand the cell..

Comment: `cell.img` is almost certainly `nil`  Have you linked the `IBOutlet` to the image view in your storyboard?

Comment: yes it's linked in the ViewCell.

Comment: Okay, my first problem is solved. I'll ask a new question for my other problems. Thanks so far